# To compiler and using shared library on linux

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, dynamic-library

I'm trying to compile and using shared library on linux. Following by linux documentation project I've created the following files:

```
//--main.cpp--//
#include "header.h"
int main(){
    char * str= "This is a string\n";
    printStr(str);
}

//--header.h--//
void printStr(char *);

//--foo.cpp--//
#include<stdio.h>

extern int var;

void printStr(char * str){
    printf("%s", str);
}

//--Makefile--//
bin: main.o foo.so
    g++ -o bin main.o -L. -lfoo.so.1
main.o:main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp
foo.so: foo.o
    g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so.1 -o libfoo.so.1.0.1 foo.o
foo.o:foo.cpp
    g++ -fPIC -c foo.cpp
clean:
    rm -f *.o *.so* bin
```

After compiling `so` library I've moved hero into the `/usr/lib/` and run `ldconfig`. Now I'm trying to execute `make`, but I've an error

```
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so.1 -o libfoo.so.1.0.1 foo.o
g++ -o bin main.o -L. -lfoo.so.1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfoo.so.1
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bin] Error 1
```

If I'm trying to move `libfoo.so.1.0` into the `/usr/loca/lib` I've the same error. Please, help me.

Comment: shouldn't the third file commented as main.cpp be header.cpp?

Comment: @BlAcKBirD I've updated it.

Comment: `-lxxx` links with `libxxx.so`, not with `xxx.so`.

Comment: @Massa I know it. And I'am create libfoo.so.1.0 in my Makefile as `g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so.1 -o libfoo.so.1.0.1 foo.o`

Comment: Repeating @Massa, `-lfoo.so.1` will link with `libfoo.so.1.so`

Comment: are trying for this ? `code` foo.so: foo.o
        g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so.1 -o libfoo.so.1.0.1.so foo.o

Comment: You should add `/usr/local/lib` in `/etc/ld.so.conf` then run `ldconfig`